# How to pass reference to $self->class->method?

Tags: perl

I am calling a method as follows:

```
$self->class->method
```

I would like to pass a reference to this method as a parameter into a subroutine.

I have tried

```
\&{ $self->class->method }
```

but I get the following error:

```
Unable to create sub named ""
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a reference to static class method, but in your case you could use anonymous closure to achieve similar,

```
my $ref = sub { $self->class->method };

# ..
my $result = $ref->();
```

Answer (score 2):

The `class` method is a little strange. I would expect a method with a name like that to return the class string, but it clearly returns an object as it has a method `method`.

I recommend that you use [`UNIVERSAL::can`](https://metacpan.org/module/UNIVERSAL), which returns a reference to the given method if it exists. So you can write code like this

```
my $method_ref = $self->class->can('method');

mysub($method_ref);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `curry` module to achieve this:

```
use curry;

my $mref = $self->class->curry::method;
```